# auto scroll to bottom of page with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i auto scroll to bottom of page with jquery becuase i am requesting xmlhttp to update content of page

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This will work in every case, no need to put a 'ridiculous' number in it:

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

Comment: Doesn't work in "every" case. I tried it and it doesn't quite scroll to the bottom. It was fixed by putting a "slightly less ridiculous" number on the end, so

$(document).scrollTop($(document).height()+500);

Comment: This appears to work at first glance, but when the element height gets to a high enough number, the scrolling stops and no longer goes to the bottom without manual intervention. The solution from Gyuri Ambrozy does not experience this issue at any element height I tested.

Comment: It has bad user experience If the element is not high enough . The solution by @Gyuri Ambrozy is perfect.

Answer (score 22):

To cover all scenarios:
Consider scrolling an overflowed div where height is not the same as scrollHeight. (remove the animate part if its not needed):

```
$('#myDiv').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#myDiv').get(0).scrollHeight
}, 1500);
```

Comment: This solution using the .scrollHeight property does not cause the "incomplete" scrolling seen with the other solution's .height() method. No added number is required with .scrollHeight.

Comment: $('#myDiv').scrollTop($('#myDiv').get(0).scrollHeight);

Comment: U r z 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

in my case it's:

```
 myscroll = $('#myDiv');
  myscroll.scrollTop(myscroll.get(0).scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 3):

This Code work for me:-

```
jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(window).height()}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Answer (score 1):

```
function scroll(){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#footerOfPage").offset().top
  }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

auto scroll to bottom of page with jquery (Best):

```
$(function () {
           $("html, body").animate({
scrollTop: $('html, body').get(0).scrollHeight}, 1000);});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LDFd7/)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the scrollHeight implementations didn't work for me, offsetHeight seemed to do the trick.

Pretty sure that scrollHeight tries to move it to the bottom of the height of the static element, not the height of the scrollable area.

```
var pane = document.getElementById('pane');
pane.scrollTop = pane.offsetHeight;
```