# how to give auto scroll to bottom when page before show

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chat

We developing chat application in that I am showing image,audio and text in the content div.

we have header div,content div,footer div.In content div adding new data dynamically i want show in bottom every time. if want see previous data i want scroll down to see. how to do that using jquery

```js
$(document)
  .on(
    "pagebeforeshow",
    "#chat",
    function() {
     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
  onFileSystemSuccess, fail);

  load = true;
  $('#opchat').empty();
  $("#preopchat").empty();
  $("#opchat1").empty();
  var checkData = storageChat.getItem("chatdata");
  if (JSON.parse(checkData) != null
    && JSON.parse(checkData) != undefined) {
   storeChatData = JSON.parse(checkData).slice();
   if (storeChatData.length > 10) {
    var sliceChatData = [];
   sliceChatData = storeChatData.slice(Math.max(
    storeChatData.length - 10, 1));
   for (var i = 0; i < sliceChatData.length; i++) {
    if (sliceChatData[i] != undefined) {
    if (sliceChatData[i].startsWith("file:///")) {
   var filepath = sliceChatData[i].split(",")
   if (filepath[1] == 'image/jpeg') {
   var storedChat = '<img class="popphoto" id="profImgDashBrd" style="height: 70px; width: 70px;" src=\''
             + sliceChatData[i]
             + '\'  >';
           previewData(storedChat);
  } else if (filepath[1] == 'audio/mpeg') {
      var storedChat = "<audio controls>"
       + "<source src='"
        + sliceChatData[i]
        + "' type='video/mp4'>"
      + "</audio>" + "<br>";
     previewData(storedChat);
   } else {
  var filepath = storeChatData[i].split(",") 
   var storedChat ="<div class='right'>" + "<p>"
   + filepath[1] + "</p>" + "</div";
   $("#opchat1").append(storedChat);
   }

   } else {
  var storedChat ="<div class='left'>" + "<p>"
    + sliceChatData[i] + "</p>" + "</div>" + "<br>";
   $("#opchat").append(storedChat);

     }
    }
   }
  } else {
   for (var i = 0; i < storeChatData.length; i++) {
   if (storeChatData[i] != undefined) {
   if (storeChatData[i].startsWith("file:///")) {
   var filepath = storeChatData[i].split(",")
   if (filepath[1] == 'image/jpeg') {
   var storedChat = '<img class="popphoto" style="height: 70px; width: 70px;" src=\''
     + filepath[0] + '\'  >';
     previewData(storedChat);
     } else if (filepath[1] == 'audio/mpeg') {
   var storedChat = "<audio controls>"
     + "<source src='"
   + filepath[0]
  + "' type='video/mp4'>"
   + "</audio>" + "<br>";
      previewData(storedChat);
   } else {
   var filepath = storeChatData[i].split(",");
   var storedChat ="<div class='right'>" + "<p>"
   + filepath[1] + "</p>" + "</div";
   $("#opqicchat1").append(storedChat);
           
    }
   } else {
 var storedChat ="<div class='left'>" + "<p>"
   + storeChatData[i] + "</p>" + "</div>" + "<br>"
   $("#opqicchat").append(storedChat);
   }
   }
   }
 }
   }
    });

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
 folderName = "QLM"
 var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
 directoryEntry.getDirectory(folderName, {
  create : true,
  exclusive : false
 }, gotDirEntry, fail)

}

function gotDirEntry(dirEntry) {

 dirEntry.getFile("newFile.txt", {
  create : true,
  exclusive : false
 }, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
 return true;
}

function fail() {
 alert("error code");
}

// Text ,audio and images Display in chat
function previewData(data) {
 var storedChat ="<div class='right'>" + "<p>" + data + "</p>" + "</div>" + "<br>";
 $("#opqicchat1").append(storedChat);
}

// Text enter and submit
$(document).on('click', '#btnchatsend', function() {
 var txtareaId = "txtarchat";
 var txtareaVal = $("#" + txtareaId).val();
 if (txtareaVal != null && txtareaVal != undefined && txtareaVal != "") {
  storeChatData.push("file:///" + "," + txtareaVal);
  storageChat.setItem("chatdata", JSON.stringify(storeChatData));
  previewData(txtareaVal)
 }
 $("#" + txtareaId).val("");
 $(textarea).val("");
});

// record audio and store
function startRecord() {
 navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {
  limit : 1
 });

}

function captureSuccess(e) {
 var audiofile = e[0].localURL;
 var audiofilePath = e[0].fullPath;
 audioname = audiofile.substr(audiofile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 filename = Date.now().toString() + audioname;
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(audiofile, copyFilePath, fail);
}
function captureError(e) {
 alert(JSON.stringify(e));

}

function playRecAudio(url) {
 if (play == true)
  audioRecord = new Media(url, onAudioSuccess, onAudioError);
 if (play == true) {
  audioRecord.play();
  play = false;
 } else {
  audioRecord.pause();
  play = true;
 }
}
function onAudioSuccess() {
}
function onAudioError() {
}

// capture image from camera

function getCapImg(source) {
 navigator.camera.getPicture(onSavedDocURISuccess, onFails, {
  destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType : source,
  saveToPhotoAlbum : true
 });
}

function imageGallery(source) {
 navigator.camera.getPicture(onSavedDocURISuccess, onFail, {
  quality : 30,
  targetWidth : 600,
  targetHeight : 600,
  destinationType : destinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType : source
 });
}
function onSavedDocURISuccess(imageURI) {
 filename = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 filename = Date.now().toString() + filename;
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, copyFilePath, fail);

}
function copyFilePath(fileEntry) {
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {
  fileSys.root.getDirectory(folderName, {
   create : true,
   exclusive : false
  }, function(dir) {
   fileEntry.copyTo(dir, filename, onCopySuccess, fail);
  }, fail);
 }, fail);
}
function onCopySuccess(entry) {
 entry
   .file(function(file) {
    storeChatData.push(entry.toURL() + "," + file.type);
    storageChat.setItem("chatdata", JSON
      .stringify(storeChatData));
    var getimageData = storageQlmChat.getItem("chatdata");
    var arrayformate = JSON.parse(getimageData);

    $
      .each(
        arrayformate,
        function(index, value) {
         var imagepath = value.split(",")
         if (index == arrayformate.length - 1) {
          if (file.type == 'image/jpeg') {
           var storedChat = '<img class="popphoto" style="height: 70px; width: 70px;" src=\''
             + imagepath[0] + '\'  >';
           previewData(storedChat);
          } else if (file.type == 'audio/mpeg') {
           var storedChat = "<audio controls>"
             + "<source src='"
             + imagepath[0]
             + "' type='video/mp4'>"
             + "</audio>" + "<br>";
           previewData(storedChat);
          }

         }
        });
   });
}

function fail(error) {
 alert("error" + error.code);
}
```

```css
.left {
  margin-top:10px;
  position: relative;
  background: aqua;
  text-align: left;
  min-width: 85%;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  left: 8%;
}

.left::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.left::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  left: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid aqua;
  clear: both;
}


 .right {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 85%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  right: 5%;
  margin-top: 10px;
} 

.right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.right::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerDiv" data-role="header"
 id="hdrIdchat" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-transition="none">
 <a class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-left" onClick="navBack()"></a>
 <h1 id="lblHdrchat">Chat</h1>

 <div data-tap-toggle="false" data-transition="none"  style="border-top:1px solid white;width: 100%; text-align: center; display: inline-flex;">  
  <div style="width: 100%; padding: 10px;">
    <img alt="" src="images/vo.png" onclick="startRecord()" style="height: 25px;">
   </div>
   <div style="width: 100%; padding: 10px">
    <img alt="" src="images/imcht.png" onClick="imageGallery(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY)" style="height: 25px;">
   </div>
   <div style="width: 100%; padding: 10px">
    <img alt="" src="images/camcht.png" onclick="getCapImg(navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);" style="height: 25px;">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div data-role="content">


 <div onclick="preChatData()">
  <p align="center"></p>
 </div>

 <div id="example">
  <div id="preopqicchat"></div>
  <div id="opqicchat" ></div>
  <div id="opqicchat1" ></div>
 </div>
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="chatfooter"
 style="background: transparent; border: none;" data-tap-toggle="false" data-transition="none">
 <div style="display: inline-flex; width: 100%;">
  <div style="width: 100%">
   <textarea autofocus="autofocus" id="txtarchat"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
   <button data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b"
    id="btnchatsend" style="width: 100% !Important;">SEND</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiKyv.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk9oI.png)

Comment: Please indent your code better... use four spaces or less

Comment: sorry for that. please see i modify the question and i attached the screen shots also it will be understand clearly

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [demo](http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/WwKRBx)

```
header,
footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

`main` grows in height with the content. The number '1' in the flex shorthand  tells how much free space in the container is allocated to the element. In our case, main is given the free space. The auto part of the value is the default size of the flex element. We want auto for all flex children.

```
main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  ...
}
```

The footer will always be beneath the content, no matter what.

**Footer starts at bottom**

[image]

**Footer gets pushed down by content**

[image]

http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/WwKRBx

Comment: we have header div,content div,footer div.In content div adding new data dynamically i want show in bottom only. if want see previous data i want scroll down only. how to do that using jquery

Comment: $(document).scrollTop($(document).height()); how to call this page before show

Comment: I don't want this to come across as rude, but I really don't understand you well enough to help you solve this. I'm sorry!

Comment: sorry andy, actual i have this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966784/auto-scroll-to-bottom-of-page-with-jquery